# Node js - how to avoid writing rules in .htaccess and use only express routing

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, express, mod-rewrite

In my local windows and linux environment, I am able to redirect or send response to the URL's using express route in main js file. For example, the below code is working in local

```
app.get('/home', function (req, res) 
{
res.send("Response sent")
})
```

When I deploy the same code in linux shared hosting environment, It throws me Cannot get/ error. But When I write the below rule in .htaccess file, the above 'get' router in main js file is getting executed and response is sent

```
RewriteRule ^home http://127.0.0.1:SOME_PORT/home [P,L]
```

This would be fine for one or two redirects. But my actual application has more route handlers and it would be ugly to write rules for all the route handlers in .htaccess file. Is there a way to handle route only using the express router instead of using .htaccess file ?

PS: I face this problem in production env only.

Comment: So in your production environment you have an Apache server in front of your node server? Is that why you can't just bind the node server directly to the ip:port you want? Are you serving something else at `/`

Comment: Yes, In prod, Apache server is also used. Is there any way to call the node server directly bypassing apache ? 

Are you serving something else at / -- You mean in .htaccess file or app,js file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your node server by specifying the port it's listening to, `:SOME_PORT` and maybe add a rule to your firewall to allow access to that port